# DataFrame user-defined function not applied unless I change column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, implicit-conversion

I want to convert my DataFrame column using implicits functions definition.

I have my DataFrame type defined, which contains additional functions:

```
class MyDF(df: DataFrame) {
    def bytes2String(colName: String): DataFrame = df
       .withColumn(colname + "_tmp", udf((x: Array[Byte]) => bytes2String(x)).apply(col(colname)))
       .drop(colname)
       .withColumnRenamed(colname + "_tmp", colname)
}
```

Then I define my implicit conversion class:

```
object NpDataFrameImplicits {
    implicit def toNpDataFrame(df: DataFrame): NpDataFrame = new NpDataFrame(df)
}
```

So finally, here is what I do in a small FunSuite unit test:

```
test("example: call to bytes2String") {
    val df: DataFrame = ...
    df.select("header.ID").show() // (1)
    df.bytes2String("header.ID").withColumnRenamed("header.ID", "id").select("id").show() // (2)
    df.bytes2String("header.ID").select("header.ID").show() // (3)
}
```

**Show #1**

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|[62 BF 58 0C 6C 59 48 9C 91 13 7B 97 E7 29 C0 2F]|
|[5C 54 49 07 00 24 40 F4 B3 0E E7 2C 03 B8 06 3C]|
|[5C 3E A2 21 01 D9 4C 1B 80 4E F9 92 1D 4A FE 26]|
|[08 C1 55 89 CE 0D 45 8C 87 0A 4A 04 90 2D 51 56]|
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**Show #2**

```
+------------------------------------+
|id                                  |
+------------------------------------+
|62bf580c-6c59-489c-9113-7b97e729c02f|
|5c544907-0024-40f4-b30e-e72c03b8063c|
|5c3ea221-01d9-4c1b-804e-f9921d4afe26|
|08c15589-ce0d-458c-870a-4a04902d5156|
+------------------------------------+
```

**Show #3**

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|[62 BF 58 0C 6C 59 48 9C 91 13 7B 97 E7 29 C0 2F]|
|[5C 54 49 07 00 24 40 F4 B3 0E E7 2C 03 B8 06 3C]|
|[5C 3E A2 21 01 D9 4C 1B 80 4E F9 92 1D 4A FE 26]|
|[08 C1 55 89 CE 0D 45 8C 87 0A 4A 04 90 2D 51 56]|
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

*As you can witness here, the third `show` (aka without the column renaming) does not work as expected and shows us a non-converted ID column. Anyone knows why?*

EDIT:

Output of `df.select(col("header.ID") as "ID").bytes2String("ID").show()`:

```
+------------------------------------+
|ID                                  |
+------------------------------------+
|62bf580c-6c59-489c-9113-7b97e729c02f|
|5c544907-0024-40f4-b30e-e72c03b8063c|
|5c3ea221-01d9-4c1b-804e-f9921d4afe26|
|08c15589-ce0d-458c-870a-4a04902d5156|
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what is the output for `df.select("header.ID" as "ID").bytes2String("ID").show() `?

Comment: @RumeshKrish I appended the result of what you asked.

Do you know what happened? Why does the 3 `show` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Reason is data frame conversion not happening for complex structure field. You are trying to covert the field value for `StructType` field. The `df.select("header.ID" as "ID")` is exploding the values into root level then you are converting field level.

Comment: I just did not understand "You are trying to covert the field value for StructType field." -> What does this mean?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: `@belka` I hope the bellow answer help's you to find the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain, what is happening on your conversion function with bellow example.
First Create data frame:

```
val jsonString: String =
    """{
      | "employee": {
      |   "id": 12345,
      |   "name": "krishnan"
      | },
      | "_id": 1
      |}""".stripMargin

  val jsonRDD: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonString, jsonString))

  val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.read.json(jsonRDD)
  df.printSchema()
```

Output structure:

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- employee: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Conversion function similar to your's:

```
def myConversion(myDf: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
    myDf.withColumn(colName + "_tmp", udf((x: Long) => (x+1).toString).apply(col(colName)))
      .drop(colName)
      .withColumnRenamed(colName + "_tmp", colName)
  }
```

**Scenario 1#**
Do the conversion for `root` level field.

```
myConversion(df, "_id").show()
myConversion(df, "_id").select("_id").show()
```

Result:

```
+----------------+---+
|        employee|_id|
+----------------+---+
|[12345,krishnan]|  2|
|[12345,krishnan]|  2|
+----------------+---+
+---+
|_id|
+---+
|  2|
|  2|
+---+
```

**Scenario 2#** do the conversion for `employee.id`. Here, when we use `employee.id` means, data frame got added with new field `id` at `root` level. This is the correct behavior.

```
myConversion(df, "employee.id").show()
myConversion(df, "employee.id").select("employee.id").show()
```

Result:

```
+---+----------------+-----------+
|_id|        employee|employee.id|
+---+----------------+-----------+
|  1|[12345,krishnan]|      12346|
|  1|[12345,krishnan]|      12346|
+---+----------------+-----------+
+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|12345|
|12345|
+-----+
```

**Scenario 3#** Select the inner field to root level and then perform conversion.

```
myConversion(df.select("employee.id"), "id").show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|12346|
|12346|
+-----+
```

My new conversion function, takes struct type field and perform conversion and store it into struct type field itself. Here, pass `employee` field and convert the `id` field alone, but changes are done field `employee` at `root` level.

```
case class Employee(id: String, name: String)

def myNewConversion(myDf: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
    myDf.withColumn(colName + "_tmp", udf((row: Row) => Employee((row.getLong(0)+1).toString, row.getString(1))).apply(col(colName)))
      .drop(colName)
      .withColumnRenamed(colName + "_tmp", colName)
  }
```

**Your scenario number 3#** using my conversion function.

```
myNewConversion(df, "employee").show()
myNewConversion(df, "employee").select("employee.id").show()
```

Result#

```
+---+----------------+
|_id|        employee|    
+---+----------------+
|  1|[12346,krishnan]|
|  1|[12346,krishnan]|
+---+----------------+
+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|12346|
|12346|
+-----+
```

Comment: Hello @RumeshKrish Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay. In your scenario #3 I don't understand why you select column "id" and no longer "employee.id". I tested locally and it works, indeed, but why? And I still don't understand why I have to rename the column before actually seeing the changes...

Comment: can you do `df.select("employee.id")` and see. you will get the single column named `id`. Data frame is immutable. you can't convert the value for any coulmn. you have to define the conversion rule `udf` or function to pass `df` and get new `df`. this is behavior. Either select and convert or define the conversion rule for `employee` column only way to get result. your case rename `header.ID` is separate the field in df. it is not selecting field inside `header`.